# What happens to the property inherited from base object when later that property of derived object is set again?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype, javascript-objects

Here **Object.create(**) is used for inheritance.

The JavaScript code:

```js
var x = {
  a: 5, 
  foo: function() {
    return this.a * this.a;
  }
};

var o = Object.create(x);

console.log('\'x\':', x);
console.log('Object \'o\':', o);
console.log('Property \'o.a\':', o.a);
console.log('Method \'o.foo()\':', o.foo());

o.a = 7;
console.log('-----After setting o.a directly-----');

console.log('Object \'o\':', o);
console.log('Property \'o.a\':', o.a);
console.log('Method \'o.foo()\':', o.foo());
```

The output for above code is :

```
'x': { a: 5, foo: [Function: foo] }
Object 'o': {}
              __proto__: 
                  a: 5
                  foo: ƒ ()
                  __proto__: Object

Property 'o.a': 5
Method 'o.foo()': 25

-----After setting o.a directly-----

Object 'o': {a: 7}
              a: 7
              __proto__: 
                a: 5
                foo: ƒ ()
                __proto__: Object

Property 'o.a': 7
Method 'o.foo()': 49
```

So at first value `a` and function `foo()` are derived from `x` object to `o` object so they are in prototype of object `o`.

But later when I set the value of `a` in object `o`, the object has a new property `a:7` as well as `a:5` is still present in prototype of object `o` and strange thing is function `foo()` is returning 49(7*7) instead of 25(5*5)**, how is this possible?

**EDIT**: *The code was run in Google Chrome's console and the output format is copied from there*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is well-documented in the [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-objects) itself

> In other words, first the object mentioned directly is examined for
>   such a property; if that object contains the named property, that is
>   the property to which the reference refers; **if that object does not
>   contain the named property, the prototype for that object is examined
>   next; and so on**.

So, *when `o` didn't have its own `a` property*, then **its prototype was examined** for the presence of that property.

But *when `a` become the own-property of `o`*, **it was picked up directly without going to its prototype chain**.

Answer (score 1):

When you tries to access a property in the object, it tries to find in that object, then in the prototype chain. So basic access via `o.a` can access the property `a` in the prototype chains until `o` does not have it's own.

When you set a prototype for an object, the prototypes properties are only used for ***read access***. You can read them, but when you will try to change it's value, here *[[Set]]* inner property does his job. It's job is when you assign a value to the property which does not exists (own properties, not those ones which are in the prototype chain), it creates a one and then assigns to it. So in your case you have no own property with name `a`, so it just creates a new property, makes it own for the `o` and assigns to it. The prototype's property is still accessible now only from direct access to the `prototype`.

In the function you have used `this`. When you call `o.foo()`, the context to which `this` refers is the object `o` and because it has an own property with name `a` and value `7`, the value `7` is used inside it.

Answer (score 1):

`o.foo()` means that object `o` calls the method `foo`, from there 
 and that means that `this` is actually object `o`.

`object_o's_property.a*object_o's_property.a` is in first case 5 * 5. Why is that? Because the search starts from the `o` object and will continue that search until it founds it or hit `null` value aka, the end of prototype chain. Again, will start the search from `o` then its `proto` and its `proto` recursively, until property is found or hit the `null`.